# Category Paths in Product URLS - Yes or No?

Tags: category-tree, product-urls

I've heard some conflicting opinions on whether having category paths in your product URLS is a good idea. An SEO guide I'm currently using suggests that Magento doesn’t support this functionality very well and it creates duplicate content issues.

In your experience, which is should I have this feature turned on or off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fine to have category paths in URL's as long as you also enable canonicals (`system->config->catalog->seo->canonical for categories/products->yes`).  This will stop any duplicate content issues.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, Jon. I have changed the settings to what you suggested. Will that take care of itself now or are there any additional steps?

Comment: When enabled just view the source code for one of the relevant pages and search for the text `canonical`. It should reveal a `<link rel="canonical" href="......" />` tag inside `<head>` which you will notice contains the product page URL but without any category path.  This is the URL search engines will use when indexing that page on your site.  All ways in which you can reach a product page through different category path's will contain this same condensed canonical URL (which is incidentally the URL you would get if navigating to the product directly from the homepage).

Comment: @JonathanHussey I have enabled canonical tag for categories and products but if a product belongs to multiple categories and are accessed from different path then href under the tag shows different values, please help! I am using magento1.9.2.2

Comment: @JonathanHussey If we enable category path in product URL then its showing error in google search console "Alternate page with proper canonical tag"

Comment: @JonathanHussey Also product url that having category name not showing in sitemap

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best SEO practice for this case is below setting(Currently Version Mage 2.2, 2.3);

> Use Categories Path for Product URL: **YES**
>   Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories: **NO** (This is so that We don't get penalize for the duplicate content issues coming from same categories for the products)
>   Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products: **Yes**

Make sure you

> set Create Permanent Redirect for Old URL

and Under Marketing>URL Rewrites> Set all products to have Redirect Type for: **Permanent(301)**

> Short Concise URL to contain two or three keywords you are trying to rank/emphasize for the product - When uploading products. 
>   Meta Title: 50~66 Character Letters
>   Skip Meta Keywords (Current year:2019)
>   Meta Descriptions 125~155 Character Letters

I would like to hear back from the community about the above setting as a best practice for SEO.